# Feedback for Vaadin wanted

Tags: jsf, gwt, ria, vaadin

Has anyone used [vaadin](http://vaadin.com/home) in a real project and wishes to share his experience? I am amidst a framework selection process for a RIA project and any feedback would really help. My key concerns are productivity and performance.

It would really nice to know how you would compare it to the more mainstream JSF+Seam stack, if you have worked with it.

Cheers!

Comment: Click the `[vaadin]` tag and explore those questions.

Comment: related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183801/should-i-use-vaadin-framework

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a list of organizations and project using Vaadin at [vaadin.com/who-is-using-vaadin](http://vaadin.com/who-is-using-vaadin/).

The performance / scalability has been nicely summarized in this video blog post: [vaadin.com/blog/-/blogs/server-side-ria-scalability](http://vaadin.com/blog/-/blogs/server-side-ria-scalability)

Comparison to other frameworks is also available at [vaadin.com/comparison](http://vaadin.com/comparison)